# Django- unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'dict' and 'dict'

Tags: python, html, django

I have doubt how to show result for "net margin" in html, which is the result of net_profit/sales.  I don't want to put this division formular in html directly, because there are many other complicated calculation apart from this.

So how can I put this division result in both views.py and html？

The following code returns the error as title.

**views.py**

```
def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(XXXView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context["sales"] = self.get_queryset().aggregate(Sum('sales'))
        context["net_profit"] = self.get_queryset().aggregate(Sum('net_profit'))

        context["net_margin"] = context["net_profit"]/context["sales"]  ---if here correct--?
```

**HTML**

```
to show result for sales： {{sales.sales__sum}}
to show result for net_profit： {{net_profit.net_profit__sum}}
how to show result for "net margin"?
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your query does not get returns a numeric value, but a dictionary:

```
context["sales"] = self.get_queryset().aggregate(Sum('sales'))
#{'sales__sum': Decimal('123123')}    
context["net_profit"] = self.get_queryset().aggregate(Sum('net_profit'))
#{'net_profit__sum': Decimal('123123')}
```

You should filter catching the dictionary value:

```
result = context['sales']['sales__sum'] / context['net_profit']['net_profit__sum']
```

Comment: Hi @Puam Dias, I got the error like "unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'Decimal' and 'float'", but in models.py, I have already declared both as "decimal", why this error still pops up?

Comment: You ran migrations and wiped the pyc?
How's your model?

Comment: Hi@Puam Dias, I have re-run migrations, all the data fields are defined as decimal in my model.

Comment: I guess the reason is because I changed the sales__sum into sales__avg, then decimal changes to float. Then how can I correct this?

Comment: Use the pdb to facilitate to identify the root of your probema: import pdb; pdb.set_trace ()

Comment: That's probably it. You could spend the query you doing now?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/93326/discussion-between-puam-dias-and-elena).

Answer (score 3):

If like this:

```
sales = context['sales']
net_profit = context['net_profit']
```

the sales and the net_profit are the object.
So, the html show net margin is `{{ sales.sale__sum/ net_profit.net_profit__sum }}`

The django template can use the cal of numbers.

Comment: Hi@xiaohen, what if I don't want to the complicated formular in template? Because I have other long formular, if I put in template, I am afraid it would slow down the speed.

Comment: And also, if I follow your example, I got this error "Could not parse the remainder....."

Comment: so, i want to know the type of sales and net_profit. Is a list or a object? and the sales__sum is a integer?

Comment: Hi@xiaohen, sales_sum is a decimal, sales, net_profit are all difined as decimal in the models.py

Comment: I know.net margin= context['sales']['sales__sum'] / context['net_profit']['net_profit__sum']